# How to set an env variable from tcl command into an xterm?

Tags: environment-variables, tcl

I want to propagate an env variable into an xterm from tcl command.
I used the followings from the xterm:

```
tclsh> set ::env(MYVAR) XXXX
tclsh> parray env
tclsh> MYVAR=           XXXX
```

But after quiting the tclsh session the MYVAR is not setted in the xterm:

```
xterm> env | grep MYVAR
xterm>
```

How to make it ?

Comment: There isn't a simple way; environment variables flow from parent processes to their children, not the other way. The parent has to be expecting something from the child.

Answer (score 1):

As Donal says, environment variables only propagate from a process to its child processes, not back to its parent.  So the simplest approach would be to start a new xterm as a child of tclsh.  Your Tcl code would do:

```
set ::env(MYVAR) XXXX
exec xterm &
```

This will open a new xterm which will have MYVAR set.  Of course I have no idea whether this fits with other requirements you may have.

Comment: I will export a file from the tcl process and read it back by openning it in tcl.
This is because the first process was ending and the variable has to be pass to the 2nd process.